# Problem with modifying JavaScript/HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a problem with modifying my code. I need to edit my code so it will not only do its purpose (the thing that it does now) but it will count from 1 to given number.

The code is in Polish and it's simple. It's purpose for now is to calculate the factorial of given number.

Here's the code:

```js
function obliczSilnie(liczba) {
  var wynik = silnia(liczba);

  if (wynik > 0) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      "<h3 style'color:blue;'>Silnia liczby " + liczba +
      "wynosi: " + wynik + "</h3>";
  }
}

function silnia(liczba) {
  if (liczba == 0 || liczba == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (liczba < 0) {
    error();
    return -1;
  }
  var wynik = liczba * silnia(liczba - 1);

  return wynik;
}

function error() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    "<h3 style='color:red;'>Błąd: Nie można obliczyć silni dla liczby ujemnej! </h3>";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Obliczanie silni</h1>

  <form name="myForm">
    <p> <b>Podaj liczbę:</b>
      <input type="number" name="myNumber" value="0" size=2> </p>
    <input type="reset" value="Wyczyść">
    <input type="button" value="Obilcz" onclick="obliczSilnie(document.myForm.myNumber.value)">
  </form>

  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: A little unclear what you want. Do you want to display the interim factorials calculated between `1` and `n`? Store them in an array. You can pass that array as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Reading code in which variables and functions are named in a language one does not know is like reading code with no proper naming at all. This makes it hard to understand what the code does and what values the variables are expected to have.

Comment: clarifying it i need to edit that code so it will do what id does now, but i need it to write numbers from 1 to n. So the final code will work something like that: it will show me the factorial of given number as it does now + it will show me, for example when i give it number 4, numbers from 1 to 4(1 2 3 4). I'm sorry if you didn't understand what i meant because of my poor English but i am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. That's my solution:

```js
function computeFactors(number) {
  //Here we use recursion with a for loop
  for(var i = 1;i < number;i++){
     var result = factorial(i);
     if (result > 0) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML +=
         "<h3 style='color:blue;'> Factorial of " + i +
         " is: " + result + "</h3>";
     }
   }
}

function factorial(number) {
   if (number == 0 || number == 1) {
     return 1;
   } else if (number < 0) {
     error();
     return -1;
   }
   var result = number * factorial(number - 1);

   return result;
}

function error() {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
     "<h3 style='color:red;'>Error: Could not factorize a negative number! </h3>";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

   <h1>Factory calculation</h1>

   <form name="myForm">
     <p> <b>Enter a number:</b>
       <input type="number" name="myNumber" value="0" size=2> </p>
     <input type="reset" value="Clear">
     <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="computeFactors(document.myForm.myNumber.value)">
   </form>

   <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```